# How to save the state of RadioList button selection in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to add a section inside of my apps settings page that allows the user to set the apps theme mode. The code I have so far works for changing the theme but the only problem that I am having with it is that it does not save the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You variable `_themeMode` get destroyed each time you dispose (close) `SettingsPage`. To make that value persistent, either save it using `Shared Preferences` and retrieve it each time your load `SettingsPage` or use `_themeMode` as global variable

Answer (score 0):

try saving your value in shared preference using `shared_preferences` plugin and then get it.